# Android thread showing result on debugging but not on running

Tags: android

I am trying to implement thread in my application. I am working with web service and fetching it to show some results. For the time being i am showing a progress dialog for which i am using thread. Following is the thread implementation :

```
final Handler handler=new Handler();    
  progDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Departments.this.getParent(), "Loading... ",
"please wait....", true);    
  new Thread(new Runnable() {  

   @Override  
   public void run() {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    suid = DownloadData();  
struid = suid.struid;
dep = Download(struid);
departments = dep.departments;
depid = dep.depid;

handler.post(new Runnable() {

 @Override
 public void run() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  progDialog.dismiss();
 }
});
   }  
  }).start();
```

When i debug the application everything seems to be fine and results are shown accordingly. However when i run the application, progress dialog is seen but results are not displayed.
Is there something i am missing?

Comment: you seem to be dismissing the progDialog from a non-UI thread. isn't it crashing ur app?

Comment: The application is not crashing. It does'nt show the results for first time but shows them rest of the time.